# Angular 7 Universal firebase routing

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, server-side-rendering

I followed this tutorial: https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/

Everything seems to be working. I can view the Angular App through my firebase hosting url.
But: As soon as I call a route directly e.g. http://xxx.firebase.app/home I get this error (copied from firebase functions log)

```
TypeError: handler is not a function
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at /worker/worker.js:783:7
    at /worker/worker.js:766:11
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/srv/dist/server.js:5145:31)
    at Zone.runTask (/srv/dist/server.js:4917:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask (/srv/dist/server.js:5220:34)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (/srv/dist/server.js:5209:48)
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (/srv/dist/server.js:6143:25)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

If I call just call the firebase url without `/home` it redirects me correctly to the `/home` route

This is what my routing looks like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'privacy',
    component: PrivacyComponent
  }
  ,
  {
    path: 'imprint',
    component: ImprintComponent
  }
];
```

Can somebody explain me, what the problem is?

Comment: http://xxx.firebase.app/imprint <-- does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, no sub-route works

Comment: potentially I had a similar Angular experience. Does
[xxx.firebase.app/home/](https://xxx.firebase.app/home/) work? (note the additional `/` at the end)

Comment: No this isn't working either..

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Second that, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and I can't find any sources to explain what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure You have **export** added to your **server.ts** file before const app. This was the issue with my case.

```
// Express server
export const app = express();
```

### update

The error is explained as follows:
- In the file `functions/src/index.ts` the variable `app` is required through the following code:

```
const universal = require(`${process.cwd()}/dist/server`).app;
exports.ssr = functions.https.onRequest(universal);
```

But, according the `${process.cwd()}/dist/server` JS file (which is the transpiled version of the `server.ts`) the variable `app` is not public so that the access to it can be obtain in `functions/src/index.ts`.

This could be seen through the way the variable `app` is declared:

```
// Express server
const app = express();
```

To overcome the issue just export the variable `app` as follows:

```
// Express server
export const app = express();
```